# How to Prevent zoom-out On an HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How do i prevent the user from zooming in on a webpage?

I have tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

but that does not prevent zooming.

Comment: You cant block it on iphones. Fyi

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use

```
content="width=device-width"
```

instead of the way you used.

I wish I helped you.

Comment: I have also tried that. unfortunately, it does not stop zooming.

Comment: Or maybe you can use "Fullscreen API".